# kafka + Error getting request for apiKey: xx and apiVersion:yy

Tags: apache-kafka

we have old brokers version - 0.10.0 ( broker based on `HDP` installation and we have total 4 brokers machines )

cluster is working fine over 4-5 years , and from last 2 days we get the following unexpected exceptions:

```
[2023-11-27 14:40:52,453] ERROR Closing socket for 192.9.231.83:9092-192.9.231.83:32584 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException: Error getting request for apiKey: 3 and apiVersion: 5
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version for API key 3: 5
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.schemaFor(ProtoUtils.java:31)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.requestSchema(ProtoUtils.java:44)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.parseRequest(ProtoUtils.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.MetadataRequest.parse(MetadataRequest.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.getRequest(AbstractRequest.java:48)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.liftedTree2$1(RequestChannel.scala:96)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:91)
        at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$processCompletedReceives$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:492)
        at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$processCompletedReceives$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:487)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at kafka.network.Processor.processCompletedReceives(SocketServer.scala:487)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:417)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I must to say that we not have broker version mismatch as for example:

when 1 broker was started on version 1.0.0 and the other 3 were started on 0.10.x ( as I already mentioned our Kafka cluster is working fine until 2-3 last days )

similar case is about - https://support.teradata.com/knowledge?id=kb_article_view&sys_kb_id=030747e2db92c098278706aaf4961909
and they recommended to Increasing `num.replica.fetchers` to 4 , but in our broker configuration this parameter already set to 8

About - ApiVersions and apiKey - https://kafka.apache.org/0101/protocol.html

Comment: Please clarify your server versions. This error happens when you use anything less than 0.10.2, so 0.10.0 or 0.10.1... "0.1" is not a valid version. Similarly, you cannot use clients newer than this

Comment: I update the post , we are using HDP Kafka version - 0.10.0 version

Comment: do you mean the reason for the exception are because producers/consumers clients not backwards with Kafka ver 0.10?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix I believe I've mentioned multiple times that you can upgrade / use Kafka outside of (now deprecated) HDP. I think HDF had Kafka 2.x while it was available